# How to bound this complex number from below?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am doing an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof ($z \rightarrow i, f(z) \rightarrow \infty$) and currently have the absolute value $$|f(z)|=\left|\frac{z-1}{z^2+1}\right|$$ and I wish to make a statement about $|z-i|$ I have made the fraction above into $$\frac{|z-1|}{|z-i||z+i|}$$ but I cannot proceed. Any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are almost done. Consider this:

$$\frac{|z-1|}{|z-i||z+i|} \overset{(\text{triangle eq.})}{\geq} \frac{|z-1|}{|z-i|\cdot(|z|+|i|)} = \frac{|z-1|}{|z|+1} \cdot \frac{1}{|z-i|}$$

Let's say you have $K \in \mathbb{R}$. Now you need to choose an appropriate $\delta$ so that $|f(z)| \gt K$ $\forall z \in B_\delta(i)$. Suppose you have a $z \in B_\delta(i)$, then $$\frac{1}{|z-i|} \gt \frac{1}{\delta}$$
which is very good (the expression gets very big for small $\delta$), because now you only need to see that 
$$\frac{|z-1|}{|z|+1} = \frac{|z-i-(1-i)|}{|z|+1} \overset{(\text{rev. triangle eq.})}{\geq} \frac{\lvert|z-i|-|1-i|\rvert}{|z|+1} = \frac{\lvert|z-i|-\sqrt2\rvert}{|z|+1}$$
doesn't get too small. 
From here it should be not too hard to choose a $\delta$.